# ActiveRecord pluck to SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I know these two statements perform the same SQL:

Using `select`

```
User.select(:email)
# SELECT  `users`.`email` FROM `users`
```

And using `pluck`

```
User.all.pluck(:email)
# SELECT `users`.`email` FROM `users`
```

Now I need to get the SQL statement derived from each method. Given that the `select` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, I can call the `to_sql` method. However, I cannot figure out how to get the SQL statement derived from a pluck operation on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, given that the result is an array.

Please, take into account that this is a simplification of the problem. The number of attributes plucked can be arbitrarily high.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  [`pluck`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L177) uses the same SQL query as `select` but it uses [`cast_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/result.rb#L99) to return an array instead of an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Comment: I am building a query based on the user input, and I want to provide feedback about the query that is actually being executed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **cannot** chain `to_sql` with `pluck` as it **doesn't return** `ActiveRecord::relation`. If you try to do, it throws an exception like so

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sql' for [[""]]:Array
```

> I cannot figure out how to get the SQL statement derived from a pluck
>   operation on an ActiveRecord::Relation object, given that the result
>   is an array.

Well, as **@cschroed** pointed out in the comments, they both(`select` and `pluck`) perform **same SQL queries**. The only difference is that `pluck` return an `array` instead of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It **doesn't matter** how many attributes you are trying to pluck, the SQL statement will be same as `select`

**Example:**

```
User.select(:first_name,:email)
#=> SELECT "users"."first_name", "users"."email" FROM "users"
```

Same for `pluck` too

```
User.all.pluck(:first_name,:email)
#=> SELECT "users"."first_name", "users"."email" FROM "users"
```

So, you just need to take the SQL statement returned by the `select` and believe that it is the same for the `pluck`. That's it!

Answer (score 3):

You could monkey-patch the `ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber` class and provide a singleton that would register any active record queries, even the ones that doesn't return `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects:

```
class QueriesRegister
  include Singleton
  def queries
    @queries ||= []
  end

  def flush
    @queries = []
  end
end

module ActiveRecord
 class LogSubscriber < ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber

  def sql(event)
    QueriesRegister.instance.queries << event.payload[:sql]
    "#{event.payload[:name]} (#{event.duration}) #{event.payload[:sql]}"    
  end
 end
end
```

Run you query:

```
User.all.pluck(:email)
```

Then, to retrieve the queries:

```
QueriesRegister.instance.queries
```

Comment: When would the `queries` array be emptied?

Comment: Well... You would need to control that yourself with the `#flush` method